# Saying kaddish for a distant relative when a closer one is alive but will not say kaddish

Tags: kaddish, family-members

What do the sources say about saying kaddish in a situation where a non-blood relative passed away. Closer relatives are alive but are unlikely to say kaddish.

Comment: Welcome to MY @fml2.  Dsiplayed just to the right of your question was the text, "Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but does not offer personalized, professional advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your rabbi." Your question as posed would be closed because you were seeking personal advice. I have edited the question to try to avoid that issue. You can always reject my edit and take your chance.

Comment: Thank you @AvrohomYitzchok!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

According to Sdei Chemed, Aveilut, if there is no relative to say kaddish (and this applies to someone who has valid relatives but they won't say it), another relative should be asked, and failing that, someone else. This is possible because all Jews are part of one soul, so we are all family.

Ideally, the person doing it should be someone who has himself lost a parent, and if not he has to get permission from his parents. If it is a non-relative, he should ideally be paid by a relative to do it. Some yeshivot offer a kaddish service.

As per the rules of this site and common sense, this is a general answer and should not be relied on just because I have the word Rabbi in my online identity. If this is a personal, practical question, one absolutely must ask a local orthodox Rabbi who knows the family, and please do not delay as this is a very important topic.

Comment: Thank you @Rabbi Kaii for the quick reply. My local rabbi told me the same.